# GNU Screen + Putty + Windows 10 constantly gets glitchy

Tags: windows-10, putty, gnu-screen

I'm using Putty on Windows 10 to connect to a Linux machine and attaching to a GNU Screen session.

Using all the same settings (exactly) on Windows 7 worked without any issues, but on Windows 10, I keep getting parts of the screen that don't refresh right, and lines that don't update and display the wrong things, and what appears to be resizing errors.

I'm not sure if I'm describing this right, but the same sessions work find on Windows 7 + Putty, but show these glitches on Windows 10.

Anyone have any clue what I should look at?
Putty is version 0.70 (x64)

Comment: Any chance of a screenshot?

Comment: It wouldn't be overly helpful since the big thing is that what's displayed is not what's actually there.  A screenshot wouldn't show it.  One such symptom is that the lines are one line off from what's displayed.  This is one example of the other type of glitches that keep happening: https://i.imgur.com/1TYPvap.png

Comment: Try pressing `Ctrl`+`L` - many applications will redraw in response.

Comment: That helped somewhat, I can see now what it's doing. In that something about when the window changes sizes in Windows 10 (either from minmizing/maximizing, or general OS stuff) it's not successfully letting Screen know: https://i.imgur.com/iOeqhVo.png

Comment: Humm... have you tried `tmux`? Does it behave similarly for you? I've not used `screen` for a long time, and `tmux` behaves for me on Win10 + PuTTY.